# error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '0' : '

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a c ++ project in Visual Studio 2013 but I get the following error

```
error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '0' : '
```

I need help!

Comment: That's not much to go on... try killing any mspdbsrv.exe processes that are running.

Comment: I do not have any running process with that name. This project was compiled in Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score -2):

I saw this error with MSVC 2017. I had a compile error in one file (missing a closing parenthesis). This error happened on all following files. Fixing the first compile error made them go away.